# Rails. Create two objects at the same time, one of which uses the id of the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Users, Projects and Tasks.

```
Users have many tasks
Projects have tasks

Tasks belongs to users
Tasks belong to projects
```

One of the fields of the Tasks Model is Project_id.

I need that when a user creates a new task, a new project is created, and the task created gets the id of the new project created in its Project_id field, so it gets automatically associated with it.

My problem is that when creating the new task, the project has not been created yet, so the project_id is null, could anyone please at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check out this portion of this page:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#highlighter_387265  I think it might help

Comment: stefan, actually my problem is not about the associations, i need the associations to be done like that, it's more a problem of how can i create a task and a project at the same time, and have the task associated to the newly created project, all at the same time. but thanks!!

Comment: in your tasks controller, `create`action, add code to create a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing it in a `before_create` callback?

```rb
class Task

  before_create :create_project

  def create_project
    new_project = Project.new(...)

    unless new_project.save
      self.errors.add(:base, "Couldn't create project.")
      return false
    end

    self.project_id = new_project.id
  end

end
```

The `return false` bit there is necessary to prevent the `Task` object from saving with an invalid `Project` and to add errors to it that can be displayed in your view.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project.